# Redirect to another page using javascript after another function finishes

Tags: javascript

I would like to redirect to the website lilas.com after an animation is played which is in javascript. I do not understand javascript that much and need help.

I would like to redirect after this `handleComplete` function is done and wait for 3 seconds.

```
function handleComplete()

function handleComplete() 
{ 
   exportRoot = new lib.Lilas(); 
   stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas); 
   stage.addChild(exportRoot);  
   createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);     
   createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage); //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling. 
  (function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) 
   {    
     var lastW, lastH, lastS=1; 
     else if(scaleType==1) 
     {  
       sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);   
     }  else if(scaleType==2) 
     {  sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);  
     }  
    } 
   })(true,'both',true,2);  }
```

Comment: What does handleComplete() executes?

Comment: can you share de definition of `handleComplete()` ?

Comment: Its an auto generated create.js animation function exported from Adobe Animate CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wait using `settimeout()` and call after function execution

javascript run in single thread so the redirection will take place after execution of your function

```
function handleComplete();
window.setTimeout(function(){

    // Move to a new location or you can do something else
    window.location.href = "http://www.lilas.com";

}, 3000);
```

Comment: I have placed according to your suggestion but it redirects before the animation handleComplete finishes. Should I attach the whole function for you to see?

Comment: @WasiRahman please go through this link. you migh get something there `http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxucMS07m9gkZWFhZklHU3p2Y1E

Here is the file for the animation @Ameya

Comment: you can use `timeout` property i guess. please go through it `http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout()` for that.

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href="http://www.lilas.com" }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what `handleComplete` function executes.

If this function executes a non async code, you can just call the other function inside a `setTimeout` like the Helmal and Ameya said in their answers.

If `handleComplete` executes an asynchronous process, you have to wait until this process finish it's execution, and then wait for 3 seconds to execute the other function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your function called "handleComplete" is async function, which means it's not coordinated with the time, to fix that you have 2 ways:

1- You need to calculate how much time needed to execute the function and then use setTimeout function.
for example if the function needs in average 50 mili seconds to be done you can do the following:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){

    // Your redirect is here
    window.location.href = "lilas.com";

}, 3050);
```

2- The second way which is more complex but more efficient is to use the callback idea, you need to change the implementation of handleComplete function and the call to be as following:

```
function handleComplete( *args*, callback) {

    // the function code, just change return sentence with this line
    return callback();
}

// the call will be like
handleComplete(*args*, function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){

        // Your redirect is here
        window.location.href = "lilas.com";

    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I calculated the time and found 12000 is fine.